# how to copy a range with groups information?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I copy "range" from one sheet to another using range.copyTo(..) function, it doesnt copy group information

```
var destSheet = some_sheet;
var sourceRange=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:H10");
sourceRange.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(1,1));
```

Values, format, formula are copied. Not groups

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, it seems that the dimension groups cannot be directly copied by `copyTo` method. So, in order to copy the dimension groups, it is required to retrieve the dimension groups and put them.

When Sheets API is used, the dimension groups can be retrieved as an object. Using this, in this answer, I would like to propose to use Sheets API. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set your destination sheet name.

```js
function deleteDimensionGroups_(sheetId, sheet) {
  var obj = [...(sheet.rowGroups || []), ...(sheet.columnGroups || [])];
  if (obj.length == 0) return [];
  return obj
    .sort((a, b) => a.depth < b.depth ? 1 : -1)
    .map(o => {
      o.range.sheetId = sheetId;
      delete o.depth;
      return { deleteDimensionGroup: o };
    });
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var srcSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // Please set your destination sheet name.
  var sourceRange = srcSheet.getRange("A1:H10");
  sourceRange.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(1, 1));

  // Copy dimension groups.
  var { sheets } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, { ranges: [srcSheet.getSheetName(), dstSheet.getSheetName()] });
  var sheet = sheets[0];
  var obj = [...(sheet.rowGroups || []), ...(sheet.columnGroups || [])];
  if (obj.length == 0) return;
  var sheetId = dstSheet.getSheetId();
  var reqs = deleteDimensionGroups_(sheetId, sheets[1]);
  var requests = [...reqs, ...obj
    .sort((a, b) => a.depth > b.depth ? 1 : -1)
    .map(o => {
      o.range.sheetId = sheetId;
      delete o.depth;
      return { addDimensionGroup: o };
    })];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the existing dimension groups are deleted from the destination sheet and the new dimension groups are copied. If you don't want to delete the dimension groups in the destination sheet, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From:

    ```
      var reqs = deleteDimensionGroups_(sheetId, sheets[1]);
    ```
  - To:

    ```
      var reqs = [];
    ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AddDimensionGroupRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#adddimensiongrouprequest)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> It's full of informations. Trying to adapt it and create a copyToWithGroup(sourceRange, destRange).. not so easy at my level. But I have materials in your answer to work with.

If you want to limit the range using `var sourceRange = srcSheet.getRange("A1:H10");`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function deleteDimensionGroups_(sheetId, obj) {
  if (obj.length == 0) return [];
  return obj
    .sort((a, b) => a.depth < b.depth ? 1 : -1)
    .map(o => {
      o.range.sheetId = sheetId;
      delete o.depth;
      return { deleteDimensionGroup: o };
    });
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var srcSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // Please set your destination sheet name.
  var sourceRange = srcSheet.getRange("A1:H10"); // In this sample, this range is used.
  sourceRange.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(1, 1));

  // Copy dimension groups in "sourceRange".
  var startRowIndex = sourceRange.getRow() - 1;
  var endRowIndex = startRowIndex + sourceRange.getNumRows();
  var startColumnIndex = sourceRange.getColumn() - 1;
  var endColumnIndex = startColumnIndex + sourceRange.getNumColumns();
  var { sheets: [src, dst] } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, { ranges: [srcSheet.getSheetName(), dstSheet.getSheetName()] });
  var check = f => f.filter(({ range }) => {
    if (range.dimension == "ROWS" && range.startIndex >= startRowIndex && range.endIndex <= endRowIndex) {
      return true;
    } else if (range.dimension == "COLUMNS" && range.startIndex >= startColumnIndex && range.endIndex <= endColumnIndex) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  var [src2, dst2] = [src || [], dst || []].map(e => {
    var temp = [];
    if (e.rowGroups && e.rowGroups.length > 0) temp = [...temp, ...check(e.rowGroups)];
    if (e.columnGroups && e.columnGroups.length > 0) temp = [...temp, ...check(e.columnGroups)];
    return temp;
  });
  if (src2.length == 0) return;
  var sheetId = dstSheet.getSheetId();
  var reqs = deleteDimensionGroups_(sheetId, dst2);
  var requests = [...reqs, ...src2
    .sort((a, b) => a.depth > b.depth ? 1 : -1)
    .map(o => {
      o.range.sheetId = sheetId;
      delete o.depth;
      return { addDimensionGroup: o };
    })];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. It's full of informations. Trying to adapt it and create a copyToWithGroup(sourceRange, destRange).. not so easy at my level. But I have materials in your answer to work with. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric Ricalens Thank you for replying. About `Trying to adapt it and create a copyToWithGroup(sourceRange, destRange)`, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood it, I apologize.